# How do I revert to an older version of the Minecraft launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

The new version of the Minecraft launcher is the worst launcher version in my opinion. I can't use mods and many things. How do I revert to an older version of the Minecraft launcher?

Comment: Have you considered using a third-party launcher like MultiMC?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 according to... who? under which law? To me, that's like saying it may be illegal to paint your football a different colour. Technically, it may be illegal somewhere, but that would be a crazy law.

Comment: @user253751 Well, they are illegal because they are considered cracked launchers, and violate Mojang's EULA. On second thought though, if you do, you probably won't get caught, but just know that it's against Mojang's rules.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 who said anything about cracked?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I think that MultiMC is legal, since you're using an official account, I think.

Comment: "Third-party" means "not Mojang", which can range from hacked ones to the custom ones we use like Twitch or MultiMC.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the old .jar folder from here:

http://launcher.mojang.com/mc/launcher/jar/fa896bd4c79d4e9f0d18df43151b549f865a3db6/launcher.jar.lzma

Note that you'll lose all configuration if you go back to the old version if you had previously used a newer one.

[image]

Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/a1r109/where_is_the_jar_launcher_from_the_downloads_page/)